# some issues with 'this' :method not applicable for the argument, also improved formatting

Tags: java, android, this

Bonjour

-A- in Appsetting :

```
public class AppSettings {
 ...
    public static String getLogFileName(Context context){
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(GPSLOGGER_PREF_NAME, 0);
        return pref.getString(LOG_FILE, "");
    }
```

-B- in Mainactivity :

```
  AppLog.logString("Version A 05 Service Started with interval " + interval + ", Logfile name: " + AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));
```

==> works fine

-C- but in

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

  File kmlFile = new File(folder.getPath(),AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));
```

the same instruction "AppSettings.getLogFileName(this)" with error (xxxx) :

"Multiple markers at this line
    - The method getLogFileName(Context) in the type AppSettings is not applicable for the arguments (SmsReceiver)
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete VariableInitializer"

why ? exists simple workaround ?

edit : adding '(' but not enough

"The method getLogFileName(Context) in the type AppSettings is not applicable for the arguments (SmsReceiver)"

Comment: Is your statement in a method (which is not the case in your post) ? If yes, it will only work if it's not a `static` one.

Comment: the both are in "private void ..."

Answer (score 0):

Missing ')' at This line?

```
File kmlFile = new File(folder.getPath(),AppSettings.getLogFileName(this); xxxx
```

Try

```
File kmlFile = new File(folder.getPath(),AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` extends `Context`.  In an `Activity` class instance, `this` refers to the current instance which is an instance of a super class of `Context`.

In your `SmsReceiver`, `this` refers to the current instance which is an instance of a super class of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Your `getLogFileName` method requires an argument of type `Context`, which is why `this` works from an `Activity` but not from your `SmsReceiver`.

Instead:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

  private Context mContext;

  public SmsReceiver(Context context)
  {
      mContext = context;
  }

  File kmlFile = new File(folder.getPath(),AppSettings.getLogFileName(mContext));
```

Then in your `Activity`:

```
smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver(this);
```

Comment: Great.  Please mark the answer as correct for other people to be able to find it by clicking the tick mark.  Thanks!

Comment: KO. in my activity have registering SmsReceiver IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" ); filter.setPriority( IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY ); registerReceiver( new SmsReceiver(), filter ); so new error "The constructor SmsReceiver() is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you can't pass a `SmsReceiver` object to the `AppSettings.getLogFileName()` method because it only accepts instances of the `Context` class or one of its descendent. SmsReceiver is not a direct nor indirect child of the `Context` class, so you can't do that.

Comment: You need to pass a `Context`. That could be an `Activity` or something else from the *Known Direct Subclasses* or *Known Indirect Subclasses* list [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).